# During the ICO and private sale, Can we lock the bonuses upto 6 months

Tags: blockchain

I am writing smart contract and stuck some where how can i block bonuses during the private sale and in ico?

Comment: Hi there. Can you clarify what you mean by "bonuses"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely. By bonuses I assume you're referring to additional tokens. 
You could simply add some pull functionality to your contract which can only be called if certain time-related variables are met.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? You mean the ERC20 Smart Contract or what?

Comment: The ERC20 interface Is only of matter to the token functionality. Assuming all tokens are created - every address contributing to the ICO/privatesale contracts could simply be assigned a bonus value and only be allowed to successfully claim the bonus if certain time-related variables are met.